Laravel 11 Database Connection Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' (Hostinger)
I'm encountering a database connection issue in my newly hosted Laravel 11 application on Hostinger. I've carefully configured the files and database in phpMyAdmin, but I'm getting this error:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: NO)

this is my .env file configuration:
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=myDataBase
DB_USERNAME=MyUserName
DB_PASSWORD=ThaPassWord
DB_COLLATION=utf8mb4_unicode_ci


I doubt Hostinger would give you root access to the database. Contact them to find out what you're user/pass should be for your database.

I missed the part where you actually have the values in .env. Check in database.php to see what keys it's looking for. I know at some point Laravel went from DB_USER to DB_USERNAME, maybe it's looking for the shorter keys?

check Hostinger panel for managing database or hostinger - How to Create a New MySQL Database
create user for your database and fill that credentials in your env file. Currently your app tries to use database as root without password which is a big NO.

Thanks for the suggestion! I can confirm that I've already created a separate user for the database and updated the credentials in my .env file. The user has the necessary privileges to access the database. but the same problem.

how did you created user  - user@which host ? And check DB_HOST and user name pass  in your .env file. If it is still same error about root@127.0.0.1 that means your changes of .env file are not accepted. try following commands : php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
to clear cache and config, double check if some of values in your .env file have space character in them if so wrap them in double quotes.

It is possible that you have the config cached (it should be in production), so, did you run the command to recache the config? you need to add more info
